# Jboss EAP 5.1 - MDB Integration with IBM Websphere MQ - Too few concurrent messages processed

Tags: jboss, jboss-mdb

I have been playing with a lot of Jboss parameters but I have been unsuccessful in getting my MDB to process more than 10 concurrent messages at a time. This is not adequate for my needs - I need a lot more concurrent message processing. I've completely run out of ideas. Does anyone have any suggestions?

My MDB (Had everything defined as a aspect domain but moved it):

```
@MessageDriven(name = "Incoming Task MDB", activationConfig = {  
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messagingType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.MessageListener"),  
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),  
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "TaskQueue"),  
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "false") })  
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)  
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.BEAN)  
// @AspectDomain("Task Queue MDB")  JBOSS Specific annotation to inject the MQ server session at runtime  
@ResourceAdapter("wmq.jmsra.rar")  
@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.DefaultActivationSpecs ({  
     @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel", propertyValue = "..."),  
     @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "..."),  
    @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager", propertyValue = "..."),  
     @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "1414"),  
     @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transportType", propertyValue = "CLIENT"),  
     @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "pollingInterval", propertyValue = "250"),  
     @javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "rescanInterval", propertyValue = "250"),  
     @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="minSession",propertyValue="100"),  
     @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="maxSession",propertyValue="100") })  
@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool (value="StrictMaxPool", maxSize=100, timeout=10000)  
public final class IncomingTaskMDB extends TaskCompletionReportable implements MessageListener {
```

The wmq.jmsra.rar version:

```
Specification-Title: J2EE Connector Architecture  
Specification-Version: 1.5  
Implementation-Title: WebSphere MQ Resource Adapter  
Implementation-Version: 7.0.1.3-k701-103-100812  
Implementation-Vendor: IBM Corporation
```

In my wmq.jmsra.rar - I modified the ra.xml:

```
<resourceadapter>  
<resourceadapter-class>  
com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl  
</resourceadapter-class>  
<config-property>  
<config-property-name>connectionConcurrency</config-property-name>  
<config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>  
<config-property-value>100</config-property-value>  
</config-property>  
<config-property>  
<config-property-name>maxConnections</config-property-name>  
<config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>  
<config-property-value>100</config-property-value>  
</config-property>
```

In my ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml:

```
   <domain name="Message Driven Bean" extends="Intercepted Bean" inheritBindings="true">  
      <bind pointcut="execution(public * *->*(..))">  
         <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.security.AuthenticationInterceptorFactory"/>  
         <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.security.RunAsSecurityInterceptorFactory"/>  
      </bind>  
      <!-- TODO: Authorization? -->  
      <bind pointcut="execution(public * *->*(..))">  
         <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptorFactory"/>  
         <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor"/>  
         <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.tx.BMTTxInterceptorFactory"/>  
         <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor"/>  
         <interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor"/>  
         <!-- interceptor-ref name="org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsFactory"/ -->  
         <stack-ref name="EJBInterceptors"/>  
      </bind>  
      <annotation expr="class(*) AND !class(@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool)">  
         @org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Pool (value="StrictMaxPool", maxSize=100, timeout=10000)  
      </annotation>
```

In standardjboss.xml:

```
<invoker-proxy-binding>  
      <name>message-driven-bean</name>  
      <invoker-mbean>default</invoker-mbean>  
      <proxy-factory>org.jboss.ejb.plugins.jms.JMSContainerInvoker</proxy-factory>  
      <proxy-factory-config>  
        <JMSProviderAdapterJNDI>DefaultJMSProvider</JMSProviderAdapterJNDI>  
        <ServerSessionPoolFactoryJNDI>StdJMSPool</ServerSessionPoolFactoryJNDI>  
        <CreateJBossMQDestination>false</CreateJBossMQDestination>  
        <!-- WARN: Don't set this to zero until a bug in the pooled executor is fixed -->  
        <MinimumSize>1</MinimumSize>  
        <MaximumSize>100</MaximumSize>  
        <KeepAliveMillis>30000</KeepAliveMillis>  
        <MaxMessages>1</MaxMessages>  
        <MDBConfig>  
          <ReconnectIntervalSec>10</ReconnectIntervalSec>  
          <DLQConfig>  
            <DestinationQueue>queue/DLQ</DestinationQueue>  
            <MaxTimesRedelivered>10</MaxTimesRedelivered>  
            <TimeToLive>0</TimeToLive>  
          </DLQConfig>  
        </MDBConfig>  
      </proxy-factory-config>  
    </invoker-proxy-binding>
```

Comment: struggling through exact same problem on Wildfly 10.1 and Wesphere MQ 8.0.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Use the annotation to increase the sessions generated from wsmq libraries. Default is 10.

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxPoolDepth", propertyValue = "100"),
```